Why does pycharm show files in python libraries when only "Project files" are selected
I am searching for files within "Project files".  Notice that only the first file is "local" and the others are embedded within various python language libraries:

When we look at the options for finding files there are options for "All places" and for "Project and Libraries". It would make sense for the embedded csv files to show in those cases.

But then why do the python library files show up in "Project files" : and is there a way to restrict search to .. well .. project files ?

Can you show the exact project structure? From settings -> Project -> Project Structure. Maybe you have added content roots?

The reason appears to be that the virtual environment directory venv is actually under the sources root.  I have excluded it now.
